# Is it possible to create composite unique constraints in Memgraph?

Tags: memgraphdb

I'm working with Memgraph and GQLAlchemy and trying to do the creation of unique constraints. According to the documentation, it's possible to specify multiple properties when defining a unique constraint. But I can figure out how. It's unclear to me whether this approach creates a composite unique constraint across the specified properties or if it generates individual unique constraints for each property.

Does GQLAlchemy support the creation of composite unique constraints, where a combination of property values must be unique across the database?